# random numbers from 1 to 100 and print the first input parameter number

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

The return type is void and the input parameter is int. I had to generate random numbers from 1 to 100 using Math.random() and using a while loop only and continually print out the first input parameter number with how many even numbers there were.

Ex:
prtEven(**5**) will print out the following even integers:
**5**6 8 12 76 44

My code prints out numbers put it isnt random, it doesnt print out the input parameter number first, and for some reason it does not output the correct number of even numbers. Could someone pls help me. While Loop only

```
public class MeLoop
{
    
    public int a, b;
    public String str;

    public void prtEven(int d){
        int count = 0;
        int number = d;
        int sumEven = random % 2;
        while(count <= 100) {
            int random = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            
            count++;
            System.out.print(count + " ");
        }
        if(sumEven == 0) {
            System.out.println("\tThere are: " + sumEven + " even numbers");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: The random number should be generated *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You define random variable inside the while loop but you also used it outside of the loop

```
int sumEven = random % 2;
```

also the parameter of the function is d(how many even number must be written)  so your loop statement should be like

```
while(count<d)
```

Answer (score 0):

if count is the number of found even random numbers the while loop should loop until `count = d`.
Within each iteration you calculate random (which you do correctly). But after each new assigned value you have to evaluate if the newly generated number is even or not. If it is even -> print it and add 1 to counter:

```
System.out.println(number);
while(count<number) {
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    if(random%2==0)
    {
        System.out.println(" "+random);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to generate d random even numbers between 1 and 100.

Try this code, it's also a bit simpler:

```
public void prtEven(int number){
    int count = 0;
    int random;
    int sumEven;
System.out.println("Input parameter: " +number);  
    while(count < number) {
        random = (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
        sumEven = random % 2;
  if(sumEven == 0) {
        System.out.print(random + " ");     
        count++;
    }  
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is poorly worded.

I believe you want to generate numbers inclusively between 1 and 100, outputting all numbers generated, but only counting the number of even numbers picked.

Note that to include the 100 in your possible random values, you need to add 1 to your value returned by `Math.random()`:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    prtEven(5);     
  }

  public static void prtEven(int d) { 
    int count = 0;
    int evenCount = 0;
    System.out.print(d + ": ");
    while(count < d) {
        int random = (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
        System.out.print(random + " ");
        if (random % 2 == 0) {
          evenCount++;
        }      
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\tThere were: " + evenCount + " even numbers");  
  }
```